# A weird syntax from a php file

Tags: php, html

I am current studying code from a existing website. I found out that my contact info of the footer is missing somehow. I am suspected this syntax can lead to the problem. Does anyone know what is that? It is in a php file.

Here is the code

```html
<div class="copyright">
 <!-- what is the [* *]-->
 [*contact*]
  <ul class="menu">
   <li>[*introtext:ne=``:then=`[*introtext*]`:else=`[[DocInfo? &docid=`[*parent*]` &field=`introtext`]]`*]</li>
   <!-- <li><a href="#">[[lang_variable? &text=`terms`]]</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">[[lang_variable? &text=`privacy`]]</a></li> -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: I am sorry, let me study how to post a code

Comment: should be okay now.

Comment: It looks like some sort of templating system, but I don't know which one. It might even be homebrewed.

Comment: What is the * is used for?

Comment: @CatchAsCatcHCan look like a MODx template / CMS system.

Comment: @Jimithus I never seen a template / CMS system before, upon some googling it seems it is the answer. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears to be the answer, I will add it as such.  The code you posted seems to related to MODx, which is a CMS and has it's own templating system.  Hopefully that gets you where you need to be.

To elaborate more fully.  MODx is a paid Content Management System (CMS) that has a template structure similar to what was posted through browsing the MODx support forums.  Since the MODx requires money to have it's code, I'm unable to provide more support for this without seeing further source code.

A template structure allows developers to give access for changing how a page, email, or other items look without requiring access to the code to change.

Below is an excerpt of a template from the [MODx documentation page](https://docs.modx.com/current/en/building-sites/elements/templates) on their template system:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>[[*pagetitle]]</title>
    <meta name="description" content="[[*description]]"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>[[*longtitle]]</h1>

Page ID: [[*id]]<br/>
IntroText (Summary): [[*introtext]]<br/>
MenuTitle: [[*menutitle]]

<hr/>

[[*content]]

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer is odd. It is both an answer and a comment. Maybe add some more details on how it looks like a MODx CMS thing? I honestly can't tell if this answer deserves an upvote, downvote, flag or just nothing. Sorry if I seem rude I just think maybe it needs some form of more details.

Comment: @TheGrandJ feel free to do whichever and have it looked at, no offense taken, if it gets removed or downvoted, that's how it goes and how the site grows :).  The real issue for lack of a better answer is that MODx is a paid CMS so I can't get access to the code to give a more direct answer.  I attempted to elevate my answer to be better, and hopefully that eases your mind.  Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: Awesome addition! This is definitely an answer now and hopefully will help the OP. Thank you for taking the time to add more.